# Invoking a custom method on multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, object

I have some identically-structured DataFrames `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3`. I want to do a sequence of steps with each of them that involve pivoting and dropping some resulting columns. Is there a way that I can define a function `bar` that does something like:

```
for df in [foo1, foo2, foo3]:
    df = bar(df)
```

but actually invokes `bar` on each of `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3`?

Comment: do you want to apply the same function to 3 different dataframes and get 3 separate results?

Comment: Pass a dictionary of DataFrames and update the dictionary by assigning the value back to the key. In this case the dict keys can be string "foo1", "foo2", "foo3", and so on. Or if you have an unknown number of dfs you can create your own keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo1, foo2, foo3 = (bar(df) for df in (foo1, foo2, foo3))
```